# Span a swarm mode cluster over multiple cloud providers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

E.g a virtual machine on DigitalOcean and another on azure. Both have a public IP and the necessary docker swarm ports can be opened.
Is there a way to create a docker swarm joining these 2 machines?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see at [rancher-os](https://rancher.com/rancher-os/) and use this tutorial [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multi-node-deployments-with-rancher-and-docker-machine-on-ubuntu-16-04) the whole point is that RacherOS uses its own network adapter